# Probability question related to gambling

Tags: probability-theory, gambling

I am struck with following problem in my research even though it looks very simple. Kindly help me with that. I have modified the question as a real life question.

A shop keeper, say outside a school, conducting a gambling. You need a pay a chocolate to play the game. First he writes a three digit number (000 considered to be a three digit number) in his hand and he will let you choose a three digit number. If both the numbers share a common unit digit he will give you back two chocolates. If unit place and tenth place also matches then he will give you 10 chocolates and if all the three digits are same then he will give you 100 chocolates. I have the following questions in this scenario:

1. Does every number has equal probability and how to find them?
2. Is this similar to any well-known probability models?
3. How badly kids were cheated by the shopkeeper and how to quantify the value?

Sorry for such a simple question.  I am working on algebra and my probability understanding is very poor. Thanks for your help.

Comment: That's a terrible shopkeeper.

Comment: You need to be a little more precise. Does 012 count as a three digit number?

Comment: Cheated? He is offering a better expected return than most lotteries.

Comment: @almagest. Yes. 012 considered to be a three digit number. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The probability that shop keeper wins is $\frac{900}{1000}$ (as all not but only unit place number number is to be different)

Probability that Unit digit is not equal = $\frac{9}{10}$.
Probability that tenth digit is not equaL = $\frac{9}{10}$.
Probability that hundredth digit is not equal=$\frac{9}{10}$.

The probability a child wins 2 chocolates= $\frac{90}{1000}$(unit place equal, tenth different, no condition on 3rd}

The probability a child wins 10 chocolates=$\frac{9}{1000}$

The probability a child wins 100 chocoaltes =$\frac{1}{1000}$

Expected value for a child is  $\frac{900}{1000}\times(-1)\  +\ \frac{90}{1000}\times(1)\ +\ \frac{9}{1000}\times(9)\ +\ \frac{1}{1000}\times(99)\ =\ \frac{-630}{1000}\ =\ =\ (-0.63)$

So, shopkeeper expect to earn 0.63 chocoaltes per round.

I don't know about the 2nd question.

Comment: $\frac{810}{900} ? $. There are 990 numbers out of 1000 numbers with different unit digit right? Plz explain. Thanks. 000 I am considering as three degit number. I have edited the question. Sorry for the confusions.

Comment: I thought you would be counting 012 a 2 digit number , is my answer correct , if not i will have to make adjustments, but normally it should be counted as a 2 digit number.

Comment: Yes. What you said is true. But in my problem, I need to  to consider 000 as three degit number. If it is not too much, kindly edit your answer. Thank you.

Comment: I read the question as implying that your *nett* winnings is only *one* chocolate when you get just the units digits correct (you've already paid one chocolate to play, but only get two back). Likewise, in the other two cases, your nett winnings are only $9$ and $99$ chocolates.

Comment: Yeah man you are correct